# routing based on interface used?

Tags: routing, tunneling

I have two internet connections. Default `eth0` and a vpn tunnel on `tun0`.

my `ip show route` shows:

```
default via 149.202.xxx.xxx dev eth0
10.8.8.0/24 dev tun0  proto kernel  scope link  src 10.8.8.234
149.202.xxx.0/24 dev eth0  proto kernel  scope link  src 149.202.xxx.yy
```

Gateway for `tun0` is `10.8.8.1` although I dont want to set it up as default. What I would like to do is for example use `ping -I tun0 8.8.8.8`, or `curl --interface tun0 http://somewebsite.com` and in this particular situation I would like to use `tun0` as my outgoing connection.

Is it possible?

Comment: source policy routing http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.rpdb.multiple-links.html http://lartc.org/howto/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what worked for me:

```
echo "10 vpn" >> /etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 10.8.8.1 dev tun0 table vpn
ip rule add from 10.8.8.234/32 table vpn
ip rule add to 10.8.8.1/32 table vpn
ip route flush cache
```

And proof:

```
$ curl ifconfig.co
149.202.xxx.xxx

$ curl --interface tun0 ifconfig.co
178.250.xxx.xxx
```